# Linear algorithm to fill a contour

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to make an algorithm that will fill a contour in linear complexity. I know such an algorithm exists. I've read somewhere that it has to do with the number of crossings, but there is a special case that I haven't had great luck in solving yet.

So far I have tried using the following algorithm. Note that I can't access previous elements (to the left) because they will/may be overwritten:

```
for (int y = blob->miny; y < blob->maxy; ++y)
{
int NumberOfBorderCrossings = 0;
unsigned int NextElem = 0;
unsigned int NextNextElem = 0;
for (int x = blob->minx-1; x < blob->maxx-1; ++x)
{
    NextElem = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(labelimg,unsigned int,y,x+1);
    NextNextElem = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(labelimg,unsigned int,y,x+2);

    if (CV_IMAGE_ELEM(labelimg,unsigned int,y,x) != label)
    {
        if (NextElem == label && NextNextElem != label)
            ++NumberOfBorderCrossings;
        else
            if (NumberOfBorderCrossings%2)
                CV_IMAGE_ELEM(labelimg,unsigned int,y,x) = label;
    }

}
}
```

The result I get is the following. The input is to the right (all non-black pixels must be copied), and the erroneous output is to the left. Note again that I only have the contour of the image to the right (not rendered).
[image]

Comment: `++x` & `++y`? Is that really what you intend?

Comment: Yes, the image has more than one row. By linear I meant linear complexity (scaling linearly with the size of the blob)

Comment: Elaborating what `fill a contour` means would help.

Comment: Did you intend the first line in your snippet to read `for (int y = blob->miny; y < blob->maxy; y++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're looking for a general [Polygon filling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).  Your line crossing counting algorithm will break where it hits single points and horizontal and vertical lines.  Have a look at [Quickfill](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm) for a possible alternative.

Comment: That is correct. I will try to implement the quickfill algorithm.